# C++ - vsprintf_s and std::string?

Tags: c++, stdstring

I have a logging function that uses '...' parameters and creates the final output string with vsprintf_s

it works fine except that I always have to use c_str() to print strings

at first I thought it was not a problem, but it's a pain to add all these **.c_str()** after each string variables, while I keep forgetting them

I though maybe a C++ guru could enlight me on this issue, is there a way to have my logging function take care of this by itself ?

```
void Logger::print(const std::string fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int len;
    char * buffer;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    len = _vscprintf(fmt.c_str(), args)+1;
    buffer = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    vsprintf_s(buffer, len, fmt.c_str(), args);
    va_end(args);
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl; 
    free(buffer);
}
```

thanks

Comment: I am not talking about the format, but the parameters obviously, since I mentioned I had to add .c_str()

Comment: How about something radically bold and fresh, like not using `printf` family of functions at all?

Comment: lol, best one of the day :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can add two variadic wrapper function templates like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class Arg>
decltype(auto) prepare(const Arg& arg)
{
   if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Arg, std::string>)
      return arg.c_str();
   else
      return arg;
}

template <class ...Args>
void printWrapper(Args&&... args)
{
   Log::print(prepare(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
}
```

and invoke `printWrapper` instead of the original member function. Note that I assumed `Log::print` to be static member function here. If that't not the case, you need adjust it. This should work now:

```
const std::string hello("hello");

printWrapper("%d %s %s", 42, hello, "world");
```

Note that C++17 is required for this to compile.

Comment: You have disabled all useful warnings a modern compiler would issue for incorrect format strings.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, that's an issue I agree.

Comment: so it's not a good idea ? I dont see any disabling pragma...I'll give it a try

Comment: @user7082181 it is not an explicit "disable", but an implied one. For the warning to work, the compiler has to see the original format string literal: `printf("%s", 3)` will warn, `const char* fmt = "%s"; printf(fmt, 3);` will not produce warnings on latest clang and gcc